# After upgrade to 13.10 64-bit I am unable to update kernel

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 13.10

the upgrade went well. However I get an error when trying to update the kernel:

```
E: linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic: subprocess installed
   post-installation script returned error exit status 2  
E: linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
E: linux-image-generic: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
E: linux-generic: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

---

```
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic.
(Reading database ... 570374 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (from .../linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic_3.11.0-12.19_amd64.deb) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Done.
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic.
Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic (from .../linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic_3.11.0-12.19_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-generic.
Unpacking linux-image-generic (from .../linux-image-generic_3.11.0.12.13_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic (from .../linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic_3.11.0-12.19_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-generic.
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (from .../linux-headers-generic_3.11.0.12.13_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-generic.
Unpacking linux-generic (from .../linux-generic_3.11.0.12.13_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (3.11.0-12.19) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/intel_microcode: 136: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/intel_microcode: prepend_earlyinitramfs: not found
E: intel-microcode: failed to prepend early firmware to initramfs
W: intel-microcode: will try to use late initramfs update mode...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-nvidia 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-nvidia: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-nvidia exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic depends on linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic (3.11.0-12.19) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                        Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Setting up linux-headers-generic (3.11.0.12.13) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.11.0.12.13); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (3.11.0-12.19) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/intel_microcode: 136: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/intel_microcode: prepend_earlyinitramfs: not found
E: intel-microcode: failed to prepend early firmware to initramfs
W: intel-microcode: will try to use late initramfs update mode...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-nvidia 3.11.0-12-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-nvidia: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-nvidia exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic depends on linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.11.0.12.13); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
 pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$
```

I have tried:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

In Synaptic I get this error:

```
E: linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
E: linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: linux-image-generic: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: linux-generic: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: linux: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: linux-image: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

When I try to install using the .deb, I get unmet dependencies...

Installing through Software Center:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18097110/Selection_014.png]

Any thoughts?

Thanks

EDIT:

I have tried manually installing, I tried a few different kernels, all saying the same thing. I guess that there is a common dependency somewhere. Any idea what would be common to all kernels?

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18097110/Selection_011.png]

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 in VirtualBox to check dependencies. And all dependencies are ok.

May be a bug, I have reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1242210

I have installed a different kernel, but same issue: 3.11.6-031106-generic

It appears not to be kernel specific, rather something missing in the packages.

I have tried to manually install all dependencies, but still no joy.

Wow, no-one has any ideas? Any help out there? Please :)

Comment: I finally updated manually using http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.5-saucy/

Comment: I have tried manually installing, I tried a few different kernels, all saying the same thing. I guess that there is a common dependency somewhere. Any idea what would be common to all kernels? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I booted the system into console. Uninstalled the kernel, uninstalled Unity, purged Gnome, uninstalled Nvidia. Then reinstalled everything, it then started working. I would not suggest this to anyone!

In the end the system worked, but with some application errors. So I decided on a fresh install, after backing everything up.